# window.resize - Won't fire until I've manually changed the browser width

Tags: javascript

I have a little code snippet here:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            $('.menu-item-810').click(function () {
                $('.squares').slideDown(2000);
            });
        }
    });
```

That says when the browsers window width is less than or equal to 768px, when you click on the element that has a class of .menu-item-810, slideDown the .squares element.

That is what I want, and it does work.. but only 99.8% correctly.

When the screen width is larger than 768px, the .squares element has a different jQuery effect, it fades in and out, instead of sliding. I needed it to slideDown instead, when in tablet/mobile view, so I wrote the above snippet.

Like I said, it all works, but say I've opened any browser, resized it to 768px or less width, browsed to the site and then click on .menu-item-810. Nothing happens. It's only when I then manually resize the browser again, by any amount, that the jQuery fires. So if I've just resized the browser again, and then click .menu-item-810, the .squares element slides down like expected, but only if I manually resize the browser. I thought that the jQuery would be listening from the start if I wrapped that snippet in $(document).ready() but that doesn't work either, it just has the same behavior as without.

Anyhoo, any help is as always massively appreciated. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Thanks guys!

Comment: less than or equal to 768px. No in your code is only less.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! And so fast too! You all rock for your input and it will be forever appreciated and respected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this makes no sense? The resize event handler fires thousands of times when the window is resized, and binding a click event handler inside the resize handler will get you thousands of click handlers.

Attach one single click handler, and check the windows width inside it

```
$('.menu-item-810').click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.squares').slideDown(2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer worked first time and is the cleanest of them all. thank you so much Adeneo!

Answer (score 0):

Once your javascript has loaded, it needs a resize event to fire in order to trigger your code. - it doesn't know if the window has been resized prior to the handler being initialised.

Put the same snippet in your `document.ready()` function to do an initial check for window size:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.menu-item-810').click(function () {
            $('.squares').slideDown(2000);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the order of your code, it is first checking the window size, and *only then, if it is small*, adds your event handler.

It sounds like what you want is to *always call the event handler*, and then *change the action* depending on the side.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.menu-item-810').click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            $('.squares').slideDown(2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Actually, now that i think some more, you don't even need to set the handler upon resize. Just set it on document load, and check the size when it gets clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item-810').click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            $('.squares').slideDown(2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it would still need to check on resize, in case the user resized the window after loading.

Comment: No, because it checks the size whenever the handler gets called.